# Create DB2 instance with 2 DB2 server versions installed

Tags: db2, instance

I have DB2 v10 and v11 server installed (LUW). I created a DB2 v10 instance and migrated it to v11.  Now when I want to create a v10 instance, it always creates v11 instances. How can I create an instance in v10?

```
/opt/ibm/db2/V10.5.11/instance/db2icrt -i instf instname
```

is what I use to create it

```
/opt/ibm/db2/V10.5.11/instance/db2icrt: symbol lookup error: /opt/ibm/db2/V10.5.11/instance/db2icrt: undefined symbol: _ZN15UtilityObserverD1Ev
```

is the message I get. No matter if I reuse the same name of the instance I migrated and deleted after that or a new name. And the instance is created as v11.

I have a root installation and the db2icrt is done as root.

Comment: you have to ensure that there is __nothing__ in the environment that refers to any other Db2 product . In other words , if you use `set | grep -i db2` there should be no result.

Comment: DB2DIR=/opt/ibm/db2/V11.1.4.4  so I need to change that to create the instance and then change it back?  
PWD=/opt/ibm/db2/V10.5.11/bin    is there too

Comment: I tried that and even deinstalled v10 and reinstalled it with new path, new users. It still creates v11 instances

Comment: Also, verify that for the newly created db2instance that its shell startup profile(s) dot in the __correct__  db2profile , and if not, fix it and re-execute the correct db2profile.   Creating downlevel instances works correctly for me in a hostname that has multiple Db2-versions installed.

Comment: @mao done. Root and db2icrt is done as root

Comment: The root user should never have a reference to Db2 in its environent variables except perhaps PWD.  Verify the db2profile details for each instance owner , i.e. that the db2profile matches the correct instance-owner, and is correctly dotted in.

Comment: That did the trick!!!! Thank you sooo much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question had two symptoms. The first syptom "symbol lookup error" was corrected by ensuring that the shell had no references (apart from in $PWD) to any Db2 product or installation.

The second symptom, db2icrt appeared to be creating the wrong version instance was corrected by adjusting the startup profile for the new instance-owner.

The solution was to ensure that the newly created Db2-instance dotted in the **correct** db2profile in the shell startup file(s) for the new instance-owner.

So for example, if the Db2 v10.5 instance-owner is db2inst8, its startup profile should dot in the `/home/db2inst8/sqllib/db2profile` , and meanwhile if the Db2 v11.5 db2instance is db2inst1 then its startup profile should dot in `/home/db2inst1/db2profile`.